# Multiple Socket Connections One PC

Tags: java, sockets

Can I have multiple Socket connections with different IPs:Ports on the same pc?

I know I have, for example:

127.0.0.1:5000

What are the others that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple socket connection with same IP and a different port number. There are many other possibilities which you can use excluding standard port numbers. Assuming you are a client, socket interface will assign a random non standard port number not in use when you call `connect()` socket function.

Comment: But when I create multiple Sockets in Java      s1 = new Socket(127.0.0.1, 5001);
s2 = new Socket(127.0.0.1, 5002);
s3 = new Socket(127.0.0.1, 5003); It returns Address already in use.

Comment: I am not familiar with java but I think `new socket` is trying to establish a connection to that IP address.

Comment: I might be more helpful if you can explain me what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @tomss That's not the real code. What's the real code? and the real exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. You can have as many connections as you like to any specific listening port, subject only to operating system limitations and, ultimately, the number of local ports you can use, which is 65535 in theory but considerably less in practice, but you can only connect to ports that are already listening. So in your example, if port 5000 is listening, you can connect to it with as many `Sockets` as you like.

> What are the others that I can use?

If that means what other ports you can connect to, it depends on what other ports are listening. If it means something else, please clarify.